# Is ArrayList a implementation that can be used as example of the SRP Principle?

Tags: java, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I'm planning a talk about SOLID and trying to getting examples of good use of these principles using the OpenJDK source code.
In my opinion, ArrayList and LinkedList are good samples of the well-applied SRP principle, because the methods seem to change together.
I'd like to get other opinions about that, as a developer, what do you think about it?

Comment: *"the methods seem to change together"* - what does that mean, and how is it related to SRP?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that, in my opinion, the methods seem to have the "same reason" to change, following the SRP principle. But I'd like to hear other opinions, what do you think about it?

Comment: The word "method" has a very specific meaning in Java. Are you referring to java methods, or simply the fact that there are 2 different classes that do similar things?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the methods of the class ArrayList. Actually, I'm talking about the whole structure of ArrayList class. The main question is, are the ArrayList class a good example of following SRP principle? https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html

Comment: With respect to the SRP, I would question whether `ArrayList` is really an object (in the OOP sense) or merely a data structure. It's probably more instructive to apply the SRP to an object that exposes some behaviors.